# Deleting existing rectangle after collision

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm creating Brick Breakers, I've made arrays for several rows (xCord-etc) and the yCords to draw and keep track of the points for each rectangle.  As you can see, I made a for loop to go through every x coordinate and detect with the ball intersects the rectangles.  My issue is I am not able to exactly figure out how to remove a rectangle as it intersects with the ball. I have been using `clearRect` and tried setting it to zero for width and height but all it does is change its color to white when it collides.

Any suggestions?

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.*;


    public class game extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {
        private static final Component Rectangle = null;
        //private static final String  = null;
        private Timer timer;
        private boolean play = false;
        private static int playerx = 650,playerY=930,panW=250,panH=15;
        private static int ballx=900, bally=600, ballxdir=-1,ballydir=-2,ballW=30,ballH=30;

    int []yCord = {0,80,160,240,320,400,480,40,120,200,280,360,440,530};// Rows of Bricks^
    int[] xCord= {1,210,420,630,840,1050,1260}; // Horizontal xPos bricks <-->
    int[] secRow ={100,310,520,730,940,1150};
    int[] xRow = {200,410,620,830,1040};
    int[] fRow = {300,510,720,930};
    int[]sixRow= {400,610,820};
    int[]sevRow = {500,710};
    int[]finRow = {600};




        for(int loc=0;loc<7; loc++) {  //top Row
                g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
            g.fillRect(xCord[loc], yCord[0], 200, 30);
            g.fillRect(xCord[loc], yCord[7], 200, 30);
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillRect(xCord[loc],yCord[13], 200, 30);  //second row
            if (new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects  //detects intersection
                    (new Rectangle(xCord[loc],yCord[0],200,30))){ 
                System.out.print(xCord[loc]+" Brick Hit\n");            
                g.clearRect(xCord[loc], yCord[0], 200, 30);
            }
                else if(new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                        (new Rectangle(xCord[loc],yCord[7],200,30))){
                g.clearRect(xCord[loc], yCord[7], 200, 30);
                repaint();
                }else if(new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                        (new Rectangle(xCord[loc],yCord[13],200,30))){
                g.clearRect(xCord[loc], yCord[13], 200, 30);

                }
        //      ballydir = -ballydir;
            }
            for (int loc=0; loc<6; loc++) {
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillRect(secRow[loc], yCord[1], 200, 30);
                g.fillRect(secRow[loc], yCord[8], 200, 30);
                if (new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                    (new Rectangle(secRow[loc],yCord[1],200,30))) { 
                    System.out.print(secRow[loc]+" Brick Hit\n");
                    g.clearRect(secRow[loc], yCord[1], 200, 30);
            //      ballydir = -ballydir;
                }
                else if(new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                        (new Rectangle(secRow[loc],yCord[8],200,30))){
                        g.clearRect(secRow[loc], yCord[8], 200, 30);
                        repaint();
                        }
                        }

            for (int loc=0; loc<5; loc++) {
                g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                g.fillRect(xRow[loc],yCord[2], 200, 30);
                g.fillRect(xRow[loc], yCord[9], 200, 30);
                if (new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                        (new Rectangle(xRow[loc],yCord[2],200,30))) { 
                    System.out.print(xRow[loc]+" Brick Hit\n");
                    g.clearRect(xRow[loc], yCord[2], 200, 30);
            //      ballydir = -ballydir;
                }
                else if(new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                        (new Rectangle(xRow[loc],yCord[9],200,30))){
                        g.clearRect(xRow[loc], yCord[9], 200, 30);
                        repaint();
                        }
            }
            for (int loc=0; loc<4; loc++) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillRect(fRow[loc], yCord[3], 200, 30);
                g.fillRect(fRow[loc],yCord[10], 200, 30);
                if (new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                        (new Rectangle(fRow[loc],yCord[3],200,30))) { 
                    System.out.print(fRow[loc]+" Brick Hit\n");
                    g.clearRect(fRow[loc], yCord[3], 200, 30);
                }
                else if(new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                        (new Rectangle(fRow[loc],yCord[10],200,30))){
                        g.clearRect(fRow[loc], yCord[10], 200, 30);
                        repaint();
                        }
            }
            for (int loc=0; loc<3; loc++) {
                g.setColor(Color.PINK);
                g.fillRect(sixRow[loc], yCord[4], 200, 30);
                g.fillRect(sixRow[loc],yCord[11], 200, 30);
                if (new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                        (new Rectangle(sixRow[loc],yCord[4],200,30))) { 
                    System.out.print(sixRow[loc]+" Brick Hit\n");
                    g.clearRect(sixRow[loc], yCord[4], 200, 30);
            //      ballydir = -ballydir;
                }
                else if(new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                        (new Rectangle(sixRow[loc],yCord[11],200,30))){
                        g.clearRect(sixRow[loc], yCord[11], 200, 30);
                        repaint();
                        }
            }
            for (int loc=0; loc<2; loc++) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(sevRow[loc], yCord[5], 200, 30);
                g.fillRect(sevRow[loc],yCord[12], 200, 30);
                if (new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                        (new Rectangle(sevRow[loc],yCord[5],200,30))) { 
                    System.out.print(sevRow[loc]+" Brick Hit\n");
                    g.clearRect(sevRow[loc], yCord[5], 200, 30);
            //      ballydir = -ballydir;
                }
                else if(new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                        (new Rectangle(sevRow[loc],yCord[12],200,30))){
                        g.clearRect(sevRow[loc], yCord[12], 200, 30);
                        repaint();
                        }
            }
            for (int loc=0; loc<1; loc++) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(finRow[loc], yCord[6], 200, 30);
                if (new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                        (new Rectangle(finRow[loc],yCord[6],200,30))) { 
                    System.out.print(finRow[loc]+" Brick Hit\n");
                    g.clearRect(finRow[loc], yCord[6], 200, 30);
                    ballydir = -ballydir;
                }

            }


        g.dispose();
        //repaint();

    }


     public void right() {  //left and right methods for keyboard inputs
            play = true;
            playerx += 40;
        }
        public void left() {
            play = true;
            playerx -=40;
        }



        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {  //user Keyboard INPUTS L,R
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if(key ==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                //System.out.print("Left\n");
                left();
            }if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                //System.out.print("Right\n");
                right();
            }



        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { //basic GAMEPLAY BOUNDS collision
    // implement code for collision against panel and right wall 
    // IF ball goes out of bounds (ground level) display GAME OVER
            timer.start();
            if (play) {


                ballx +=ballxdir;
                bally -=ballydir;

                if (new Rectangle(ballx, bally,ballW,ballH).intersects
                    (new Rectangle(playerx,playerY,panW,panH))) { 

                    System.out.print("HIT");
                    ballydir = -ballydir;
                }


                //ballydir = +ballydir;
                //left wall collision
                if (ballx <1) {
                    ballxdir =-ballxdir+1;
                    System.out.print("SPEED INCREASE: "+ballxdir+" LEFT HIT\n");
                }
                //RIGHT wall collision
                if (ballx>1455) {
                    ballxdir= -ballxdir+1;
                    System.out.print("SPEED INCREASE: "+ballxdir+ " RIGHT wall HIT\n");
                }
                //GROUND collision(collision not needed) Change to display JFRAME of "GAME OVER"
                if (bally>925) {
    //          bally=500;//start position
    //          ballx=900;  
                System.exit(0);
                }

                //celling collision
                if (bally <-1) {
                    ballydir =-ballydir-1;
                    System.out.print("SPEED INCREASE: "+ballydir+" Celling HIT\n");
                }
                //PANEL OFF SCREEN PREVENTION BOUNDS
                if(playerx>1223) {
                    playerx=1223;
                    System.out.print("Out Of Bounds\n");
                }if (playerx<1) {
                    playerx =1;
                    System.out.print("Out Of Bounds\n");



                }

            }
            repaint();

        }
```

Comment: *"(Note, I'm only adding part of my code that contains the graphics which I believe is the only thing relevant for this issue.)"* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `I have been using clearRect... change its color to white when it collides.` That is what `clearRect` is supposed to do. It fills given rectangle with color that is currently set as background color of the component. Instead of `clearRect` just paint over the rectangle you want to delete with color of the background.

Comment: Suggestion, do your painting in `paintComponent` method. Keep the collision code out of the painting code. Instead make a model that would hold position of the bricks. when collision happens remove the brick from the model and just repaint the component based on the new model.

Comment: I agree with @MatheM. Create a reasonable class design for your game that models the necessary interactions. This will be much cleaner and easier to maintain than the multitude of arrays that you currently have.

Comment: How do you mean?   The arrays are the xCord for each brick for each row.  Do you mean to make another class with the same arrays and add the collision code of new Rectangles and implement it with the paint method?

Comment: Noting the latest edit: Unused imports, >230 LOC & a heaping helping of compilation errors does not make for an MCVE.

Comment: I have no Idea how that is supposed to help me.